# how to know if noatime or relatime is default mount option in kernel?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, stat

I was trying to know if relatime or noatime was set on a filesystem, but i didn't found the information, neither in /etc/fstab, neither in kernel boot options.

First of all, it seems clear that i don't have the "normal" behaviour on atime:

```
root@antec:/tmp# rm -f test.txt; echo a>test.txt

root@antec:/tmp# stat test.txt | \grep -i 2011
Access: 2011-08-01 21:54:30.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2011-08-01 21:54:30.000000000 +0200
Change: 2011-08-01 21:54:30.000000000 +0200

root@antec:/tmp# cat test.txt > /dev/null

root@antec:/tmp# stat test.txt | \grep -i 2011
Access: 2011-08-01 21:54:53.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2011-08-01 21:54:30.000000000 +0200
Change: 2011-08-01 21:54:30.000000000 +0200

root@antec:/tmp# date
Mon Aug  1 21:55:00 CEST 2011

root@antec:/tmp# cat test.txt > /dev/null

root@antec:/tmp# stat test.txt | \grep -i 2011
Access: 2011-08-01 21:54:53.000000000 +0200 <--- atime not modified
Modify: 2011-08-01 21:54:30.000000000 +0200
Change: 2011-08-01 21:54:30.000000000 +0200
root@antec:/tmp#
```

I have two questions:
- Is noatime or relatime a default mount options, and if yes, from which kernel release ?
- Is there a way to see the default mount options (ie: how can i see why i don't have the "normal" atime behaviour ?)
Many questions but i think they are related. Feel free to edit the title if you have a more explicit title.

Comment: maybe ask at serverfault.com

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should list all the options a file system was mounted with:

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

Comment: thanks. I see that "mount" does not show everything! Do you know where do the "additionnal" mount options (ie: those shown in /proc/mounts but not in /etc/fstab) come from ? I mean, where the kernel reads them ?

Comment: The kernel contains the default values appended as file system options if no particular value is specified. The exact values of the default options are contained in the kernel config when you compile the kernel.

Comment: google returns nothing on "CONFIG_ relatime" and `grep -i relatime .config` returns nothing on my machine. What did i miss ?

Comment: Check http://kerneltrap.org/node/14148

Comment: The link talks about a "CONFIG_DEFAULT_RELATIME" kernel option, but i cannot find this option, it is not in the kernel sources (I have check in 2.6.36 and 3.0), neither in my .config. I don't understand why CONFIG_DEFAULT_RELATIME does not exist in the kernel sources

Comment: Or just type `mount` without any parameter, that's gonna basically do a `cat /proc/mounts` but it's a nice shorthand.

Answer (score 3):

This question is pretty old, but you can look at default mount options for an ext filesystem with:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/<device>
```

Comment: And how would someone install that program, since it does not appear to be a standard inclusion?

Comment: @underscore_d use "apt-get install e2fsprogs" or the appropriate local equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`nfsstat -m` will give you a listing of all NFS mounts and flags.

With that said, I had to use `cat /proc/mounts` on an older 2.6.5 kernel, since nfsstat -m wasn't supported then.